# indexpath of cells in grouped tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

i have a table view, split into alphabetical sections, populated from array that has been filtered

how can i track the "true" indexpath of cells in a grouped tableview. 
instead of the count starting at 0 for each section.

i need to get this so i can access the right bit of data from an array

at the moment it works like this(just in case im not clear)

(section 0)
row 0
row 1
row 2
(section 1)
row 0
row 1
etc...........

i need to get it so i can get

section 0)
row 0
row 1
row 2
(section 1)
row 3
row 4

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger index=0;
    for( int i=0; i<indexPath.section; i++ )
        index += [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];

    index += indexPath.row;

    return index;
}
```

It assumes that this method is placed in a UITableViewController class.
You can use it like this:

```
NSUInterger realIndex = [self indexFromIndexPath:indexPath];
id myObject = [dataArray objectAtIndex:realIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to get correct row,

```
NSUInteger row = 0;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < noofsectionsinTableView; i++)
   row += [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
return row;
```

Comment: sorry , but what do you mean by datasource? , the tableview , of the array with my data , neither respond to numberOfRowsInSection  ---sorry if i am being daft

Comment: sorry to be a pain , but do you have an example of how you used it?

Comment: may i know where you want to implement this?

Comment: huge thank you for your help, but i have used jens answer , but you were a massive help